# Clang/gcc use different c++ standard for header and main

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, cimg

I was using `CImg` for picture processing, which don't compile for C++11 or above:

```
CImg.h:48902:22: error: there are no arguments to 'pclose' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'pclose' must be available [-fpermissive]
```

But my program which includes `CImg.h` does use some C++11  feature. Can I use different C++ standard to process these two files? `CImg.h` itself is a header+code so I have to `#include` that.

Here is my test program:

```
#define cimg_display 0
#include "CImg.h"
int main(){}
```

`CImg.h` comes from the lastest version from `http://cimg.eu/`.

Comment: `pclose` is a POSIX function (or maybe it's from somewhere else entirely and has the same name) and is not part of C++. More information is required to give assistance.

Comment: I'm under Cygwin. The compilation do passes without `-std=c++11`

Comment: @ZisIsNotZis It's likely that using -std with any main C++ standard would give that result, Clang and GCC will be restrictive about what non-standard functions they allow when you explicitly specify a standard. For GCC, `-std=gnu++11` might work, but even if it does I believe there should be a better way of specifying it.

Comment: You refer to 2 files but only show one - where is the other one? What command do you use to compile?